# Typing phonegap after installing Phonegap does nothing! *Elementary OS*

Tags: node.js, cordova

I installed phonegap on my system using command **sudo npm install -g phonegap@latest**.

But then when i type phonegap to run it nothing happens.
I am new to this.

If you require any more info i'll be happy to provide you.

I have attached the snapshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4jm2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i followed this post and it worked. Probably the link b/w node and nodejs was not functioning as it should. Recreating it fixed it for me:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/538996/executing-certain-commands-do-absolutely-nothing